# Brilliant Retail: change order number

Tags: ecommerce, brilliantretail

I have just configured a test site using a fresh install of Brilliant Retail, and it appears the first order number starts with 10000.

Is there a way to change this default starting number? I looked in the settings but either I'm just not seeing it, or it doesn't exist as a user configurable option. In case my client asks, I would like to know if it is possible to change this figure at all?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The next order number is set the br_config_data table. Look for the 'label' column with the value 'Order ID' and you'll see the next order id in the 'value' field.

You'll want to make sure that its greater than any existing orders in the database since the value is auto incremented.